# how to remove mp3 Subtitles

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mp3, subtitles

How to remove embedded subtitles from a MP3 file in Linux?

I have a mp3 file with subtitles in it (it is sound of a movie in another language , so you don't have to download the movie again just the sound and it can be merged to the mkv file)
The subtitle is translation for captions/text in film

If I play the mp3 file with  "Videos" (default Ubuntu video player) it plays fine but if I do

```
lame myfile.mp3 newfile.mp3
```

Which should output an identical file, which it does without subtitles but when I try to play that it contains lots of noise/weird sounds. So my guess is that it parsed the subtitles as if they were part of sound.

**so the question is** how to get rid of any additional embedded stuff in a mp3 file preferably with tools available in linux (Ubuntu)?

As to why I need this is because I need to convert file format and lame doesn't handle this extra embedded stuff well , if you know a converter program capable of handling mp3 subtitles well that would do too.

After some googling it seems the subtitle is embedded similar to how lyrics are , which is some kind of id3 tags. I installed "id3" (a command line tool for Ubuntu which can manipulate id3 tags) but it didn't detect any tags in file . (lyrics are in id3v3 I think)

Images of Properties Windows and Subtitle options

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you sure it is really mp3 file and not some sort of video just renamed to .mp3? I don't think "subtitles" can be embeded in mp3.

Comment: @edvinas.me i wanted to add some images to post but it didn't allow me ... it says "MPEG1 Layer3 (MP3)" for codec in properties window

Comment: you can add it to imgur.com and post the link :)

Comment: MPEG1 Layer3 is video format if I remember correctly.

Comment: @edvinas.me added images

Comment: "MPEG-1 or MPEG-2 Audio Layer III, more commonly referred to as MP3, is an encoding format for digital audio" from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3) ... so no its not video

Comment: image urls don't work though (access forbidden) :/ Well, maybe there are any `*.srt` or `*.sub` files in directory that player is loading together with `.mp3`?

Comment: no its just the mp3 , i will upload somewhere else now

Comment: @edvinas.me updated links , they should be ok now .

Comment: looks like like a MKV video file with mp3 audio and a mp3 extension

Comment: @Sathya yes it seems like that , i didn't noticed the Matroska container before ... , tnx for the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [MkvToolNix](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/downloads.html#ubuntu) set of tools. The mkvmerge tool can do exactly what you want.
Simply open your file  -which is in matroska container format- in mkvmerge, choose the track you want to remove (the text track since you want to remove subtitles), uncheck it, and remux.
It'll take a few seconds and won't re-encode everything else. While there, you may want to make sure Compression is set to "none" explicitly on the extra options tab for each track to ensure maximum compatibility.